# Force trailing slash for a specific url with htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have been viewing the other posts on stackoverflow.com about forcing a trailing slash, however, I can not seem to find a post regarding forcing a trailing slash for one specific url, and the scenarios I have found break other parts of the site.

Here is my dilemma. I have the following URL

```
http://www.example.com/directory
```

However, due to legacy code, and relative paths, the CSS is not showing when that URL is viewed. When a slash is added to the end, the CSS and everything else works great. So what I would like to do is force a trailing slash for that specific URL and no others.

Example of url to force trailing slash

```
http://www.example.com/directory
```

Example of above url with trailing slash

```
http://www.example.com/directory/
```

Example of another url that I do not want to force a trailing slash

```
http://www.example.com/directory/foo
```

Any ideas, thoughts, suggestions, or comments are greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use .htaccess to do this

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^directory$ directory/
```

Comment: Negative, Thank you for your response ilovecode, however, the page is still not finding any of the relative paths =[

Comment: Change `^directory$` and `directory/` to absolute URLs. Are you sure the RewriteEngine module is loaded/available to you?

Comment: Rock n roll, that did it!

Comment: Awesome man, definitely read up on `.htaccess` and particularly the `RewriteEngine`.